# Setting constraints for Dynamic Type for 5 labels

Tags: ios

We have a tableViewCell and 5 labels in to it.

3 labels goes vertically to the left side(label #2 is in the middle) and 2 goes vertically to the right side(one label is on the top, another on the bottom).
I wonder, what constraints are needed to get properly working labels when user changes text size?

Comment: Post a screenshot of the desired layout.

Comment: http://cdn.imghack.se/images/019c7587dca3d39683a98a1200b2a5df.png

Comment: Labels have an intrinsic content size. So you'd just have to specify constraints for the position of the label.

Comment: Yes, I did it. I forgot to mention, that cell itself is resizing also. And when it is getting smaller, content of that cell is messed up.

Comment: Show us all your constraints.

Comment: I'm sorry for taking so long. I was trying to set the right constraints, but unfortunately views doesn't look correctly. At the moment my constraints are following:
http://cdn.imghack.se/images/8343d20ae02ace2207e716d1a94326be.png
http://cdn.imghack.se/images/450b4483dc65709bbc853b1aa030ebbb.png

Comment: Which of the labels you mentioned can change their vertical size?

Comment: Well, they all can, because of setting higher or smaller text size by user.

Comment: Don't use inequality constraints for that. Make your layout 'tighter'.

Comment: I am sorry, but when text is getting larger then cell's height is also getting larger and constrait will brake as far as I know.

Comment: You need to fix the code for your cell height then.